# Xcode: How do I pass the value of my Int from the UIview to the next UIViewcontroller easily?

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, int

In my UIView "Fråga", you get questions, and after 20 questions you get a button called "ratta". when you hit"ratta" the app will count how many correct answers you got and store it in the integer "antalratt". Also when you hit the ratta button, you should be redirected to a UIViewController called "Rattning". There is a label in "Rattning" called ratttext! I want the label ratttext to show the value of antalratt! I have an integer in "Rattning" called antratt, which can be used to collect the value from the previous view!

Summary: Fråga is the first view, where the antalratt is counted. Rattning is the second view controller, where the antalratt should be transferred. The variable that should pick up antalratt there is antratt.

Can anyone try to describe what I should do, very detailed? Like everything I have to #import and where and so on :P I'm very new to obj-c, so try to make it simple ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're asking a question about passing a value between view controllers and looking for a very detailed explanation, including imports.  I'm suspicious that if you got a detailed answer you would not be able to understand it.  Have you tried looking at the hundreds (really hundreds) of Xcode examples?  Every single example that involves two or more controllers _will_, actually _must_, transfer values between one another.

Answer (score 0):

To go to another view from one view you can use Navigation Controller. Open your AppDelagate.m (or whatever you've called your delegate file) and locate the following function:

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

And add this code

```
Fraga *fraga=[[Fraga alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fraga];
self.window.rootViewController=navController;
```

Now in you Fraga.m file import rattning.h and create a function result (for example) like so:

```
- (IBAction)result:(id)sender {
      Rattning *rattning = [[Rattning alloc] initWithNibName:@"RattningView" bundle:nil];
      // RattningView must be the name of your view or nib file
      rattning.antratt=self.antalratt;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:rattning animated:YES];
}
```

Then link this function to a button. 
And in you Ratning.m file, locate the viewDidLoad function and add

```
 ratttext.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", self.antratt];
```

I've answered assuming that you already have your two views ready. If yes then it should work.

Comment: should antratt and antalratt be int?

where should I import what?

Comment: Thank you! But it is not working :( It says it couldnt find the property of navigationController or antalratt on object of 'fråga'!

Comment: i provided you with an example you'll have to adapt it to your code. antalrat is the int you said you used in Fraga. How about you provide your code, it'll be easier to see what's wrong

Comment: Im sorry, I think I can't use the delegate file, I've heard it will slow the app down. I will have to send loads om values later on :O

Comment: well then you can start with a navigation controller and add your first view to the navigation controller. that way you can skip the delegate part and work with the rest. good luck